# where do i need to paste the code to send html mark up email?

Tags: html, html-email

I want to write an email for   rsvp action to my friends. I have written the code in note pad. where do i  paste the code  to  create html mark up email? Please help me.

Comment: the code needs to be saved in a server-side-tech file like jsp/php of your choice and the application/web server. What is unclear here is (a) what technology are you using and (b) your code, as that might be giving us an idea of code

Answer (score 1):

The likes of Gmail and others won't let you paste HTML source code as your email. You could display your HTML constructed document in your browser and copy/paste it into your email. This way formatting and images should be kept if your email is HTML enabled.

Comment: To clarify, view your html as a webpage in a browser and copy all `ctrl+a` the rendered html and paste that in instead. The images will only email if they are hosted online (relative links won't work) @user3135649

Answer (score 0):

make sure your email client (thunderbird, yahoo, hotmail etc) is set up to send html email in your settings and then simply paste the html into the body of the message. if you are in the clients "html" edit mode you should be good to go.